# How to manage before or after scenario methods in listener?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, ui-automation, build-automation, testng-eclipse

I wanted to know if we can maintain login in more than one scenario present in same bdd file. Is there any listener where I can manage in it. Like before or after scenario present in that listener. 
Would like to know more about same approach.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: Can you add more context to the question? Are you using Cucumber-JVM along with TestNG? What do you mean by **login** in scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by **Cucumber Hooks**, called as `@Before` `@After`

That can be used for each scenario to login in multiple BDD files,